# Why this integral by parts not work?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Suppose we have the original integral 
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln(t+a)e^{-t}e^{-e^{-t}}dt,
\end{equation}
where $a$ is a positive constant. With the integral by parts, we can rewrite the above integral as
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln(t+a)de^{-e^{-t}}\\
&=\ln(t+a)e^{-e^{-t}}|_{0}^{\infty}-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-e^{-t}}}{t+a}dt.
\end{align}
Obviously, the first term is infinite, which means that we cannot rewrite the origital integral with the integral by parts, but WHY?

Comment: The $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-e^{-t}}}{t+a}dt$ diverge, so we really have an indeterminate form $\infty-\infty$, but I don't see how to calculate the integral....

Comment: i would add  $0=1-1$ in your last integral (to be more formal you should replace all upper limits by $L$) . this will produce a convergent term plus something which has exactly the same typ of singular behaviour as your first term. this will cancel the artifical divergence and you can take the limit $L \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: the correct result then reads

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\log(t+a)e^{-t}e^{-e^{-t}}dt=-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-e^{-t}}-1}{t+a}
$$

which converges superfast

Comment: @tired: Thank you very much for your interesting comment. But it is not very clear to me. Could you please describe it in a little more detail? Thanks again!!

Comment: @EmilioNovati: Thanks for your comment, you found the source!

Comment: We want to integrate by parts

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\underbrace{\log(t+a)}_{u(t)}\overbrace{e^{-e^{-t}}e^{-t}}^{v'(t)}dt
$$

the problem here is that $u(t)$ is singular at the upper limit whereas $v(t)$ approaches a constant. This happens frequently and might be fixed as long as the singularity is artifical (so only a result of IPBs) by 

a) introducing a limit procedure and 

b) by adding and substracting the singular part after the first IPB

----

Comment: -----
In your example

$$
\int_{0}^{L}\log(t+a)e^{-e^{-t}}e^{-t}dt=\log(t+a)e^{-e^{-t}}\big|_0^L-\int_0^L\frac{e^{-e^{-t}}}{t+a}=\log(t+a)e^{-e^{-t}}\big|_0^L-\int_0^L\frac{1}{t+a}-\int_0^L\frac{e^{-e^{-t}}-1}{t+a}
$$

Can you see what happens now?

Comment: @tired: I'm sorry but I don't get why the term $\log(t+a)e^{-e^{-t}}|_0^L$ can be cancelled by the term $-\int_0^L\frac{1}{t+a}dt$. I tried to calculate the numerical integration of the original integral and your simplified one in MATLAB with the following code: funA = @(t) log(t+a).*exp(-t).*exp(-exp(-t));
funB = @(t) (1-exp(-exp(-t)))./(t+a);
resultsA  = integral(funA,0,inf);
resultsB  = integral(funB,0,inf); They give different results.

Comment: the lower boundary term doesn't cancel (it is $\log(a)(1-e)$) but divergent piece from the upper boundary vanishs since $e^{- e^{-x}}\sim 1-e^{-x}$ for $x\rightarrow \infty$

Comment: @tired: Thank you, you are really professional! BTW the offset should be $\log(a)(1-e^{-1})$.

Answer (score 1):

Your method seems fine at first glance, but try re-writing the improper integral as the following (Improper integrals cannot be computed using a normal Riemann integral.)

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln(t+a)e^{-t}e^{-e^{-t}}dt = \lim_{L\to\infty}\int_{0}^{L}\ln(t+a)e^{-t}e^{-e^{-t}}dt$$

Then carry on as you are and place the limit in at the end of the evaluation.

Comment: Thanks for your information. But it seems not very helpful if using your described method, because we cannot further simply the integral form after using the integral by parts.

Comment: @kawofengche. The fact that you cannot simplify the second integral does not change the problem.